# Dymo DLS/SDK Framework and Qt Creator?

Tags: c++, qt, g++, mingw, dymo

I am using Qt Creator with a C++ Desktop Application mode, using MinGW g++ and qmake. 
I have downloaded the Dymo DLS/SDK framework and installed it to my computer (Win 8). 
**I am looking for some one who has had experience with the Dymo DLS/SDK framework and how i might get started either with including source files or referencing the framework for very simple use.** In most cases i get many include errors for header files that are specific to visual studio but i feel that in most cases there is no need for most of them as they seem UI related.
Any help or references would be appreciated.

Comment: JaredTS486, are you referring to the Javascript label framework that Dymo puts out?  If so, I have used it on the web for business applications, and I can be an authoritative reference.  Feel free to post any errors you are encountering.

Comment: I am currently using C# for the Dymo label framework and referencing the framework .dll files. The issue i was having with Qt is i could not seem to reference the correct libraries in the same way and could not compile. There seemed to be an endless trail of libraries needed that the dymo framework reference required. Otherwise the C# code we have now is only 5 lines to print, very simple, works great.